# All of them are wearing an orange shirt. OR All of them are wearing orange shirts

Tags: plural-forms

Let's say there're three boys, and they all are in an orange shirt. Then, which one is correct?

*A. All of them are wearing an orange shirt.*

*B. All of them are wearing orange shirts.*

Of course, each of them is wearing ONE orange shirt, but because all of them are in a orange shirt, there're three orange shirts. So I'm confused.

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/36130/is-it-all-right-to-say-all-men-have-one-head

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of single v.s. plural:

*All of them are wearing orange shirts.*

v.s.

*Each of them is wearing an orange shirt.*

This is because the first sentence refers to multiple shirts (on multiple people) and the second sentence refers to the single shirt worn by each member of a group of people.

Comment: If so, are those two sentences the same in meaning? How can you describe this:http://www.leedsbuildingsociety.co.uk/_resources/img/press/2013-09/thumbs/heart-and-sole-tb.jpg?

Answer (score -2):

> All of them are wearing orange shirts.

Is the correct one.

Comment: You might want to explain why this is the case, so the OP can better handle these situations in the future.