# Does “Both Amy and I are wearing a scarf” sound right?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I’ve searched my question on the site and found a similar one [All of them are wearing an orange shirt. OR All of them are wearing orange shirts](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/30035/66508)

I’ve read it and I feel there might be a slight difference between my question and this one.

> All of them are wearing an orange shirt.
>
> Both Amy and I are wearing a scarf.

Of course, each person is wearing a scarf.

In the sentence, “Amy” and “I” sound more like two individual people, different from “them”.

So does “Both Amy and I are wearing a scarf” sound right?

Do I still have to say “Both Amy and I are wearing scarves.”?

Comment: Well, **them** meas more than one. So, referring to two individual people as them is totally fine.

Comment: Yes, if you use the distributive "both", you should use the plural "scarves", although there are a lot of times that native speakers just choose not to adhere to this rule; however, the distributive "each" means that you must use the singular.

Comment: The most natural wording for me is "Amy and I are both wearing scarves."

Answer (score 4):

Remember, you can replace, **"Amy and I"** with the pronoun, **"We"**. This means that the subject is still plural. So, we'd have to use the plural, **"Scarves"** in this case.

However, if you want to talk about individual clothing choices, you'd use something like,

> "Amy and I are each wearing a scarf."

The **"each"** refers to each person performing the action, regardless of how many people are doing it.